# How to create login-password field with radtextbox and remember info?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, textbox, passwords

small problem with telerik bibilotheque. The problem came from my login page or I use two fields: (login and password) with controller 'radcombobox'. And every time I return to the login page, login information are saved and re-write over the fields through the cookie. Until everything works. But when I click the button connection. I will return an error login .... I do not understand why because the values ​​of the fields look OK.

!! If i use [asp:textbox] all is good but with [radtextbox] not ..
Here is my code for both fields (login and password with the button)
Thanks a lot

```
 <tr>
            <td class="labelCo">
                <asp:Label ID="lbLogin" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:IRM, user_label_identity %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="inputCo">
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtBoxLogin" Runat="server" Width="300px" AutoCompleteType="None">
                </telerik:RadTextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labelCo">
                <asp:Label ID="lbPassword" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:IRM, user_label_password %>' ></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="inputCo">
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtBoxPassword" Runat="server" TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="None"  Width="300px" ></telerik:RadTextBox> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="btnconectCo">
                <asp:Button ID="btnConnect" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:IRM, global_button_connect %>' OnClick="btnConnect_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And buttonClick ... A long code ^^

```
try
            {
                string name;
                string password;

                name = txtBoxLogin.Text.Replace("'", ""); ;
                password = txtBoxPassword.Text.Replace("'", "");

                if (name.Trim().Length >= 3 && password.Length >= 3)
                {


                    general_function myFunction = new general_function(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCI2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                    //Récupère la connection de l'utilisateur dans la BD ARMS_USER
                    string[,] resultArmsUser = myFunction.sql_request2D("getInfoUserAuthentification '" + name.Trim() + "','" + password.Trim() + "'");
                    int countConnection = resultArmsUser.GetLength(0);

                    if (countConnection > 1)
                    {
                        object[] sessionUser = new object[4];
                        sessionUser[0] = resultArmsUser[0, 1]; //login
                        sessionUser[1] = password; //stock le password
                        sessionUser[3] = resultArmsUser; //Stocke les infos du user
                        Session["sessionUser"] = sessionUser;
                        Session["user_name"] = name;
                        Session["user_password"] = password;


                        Session["userDb"] = null;
                        string res = string.Empty;
                        for (int a = 0; a < resultArmsUser.GetLength(0); a++)
                        {
                            res += resultArmsUser[a, 5].ToString() + "#" + resultArmsUser[a, 3].ToString() + "{-}";
                        }
                        Session["userDb"] = res;

                        creatTableConnection_withoutWindowsLogin(countConnection, resultArmsUser);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (resultArmsUser[0, 0] != "")
                        {

                            string userID = myUser.getUserIDAtAuthentification(name, password, resultArmsUser[0, 3]);


                            if (userID != "")
                            {
                                myFunction = new general_function(resultArmsUser[0, 3]);

                                Session["logged"] = true;
                                Session["userID"] = userID;
                                Session["user_name"] = name;
                                Session["user_password"] = password;
                                string[,] nothing = new string[0, 0];
                                myFunction.addActivity("user", int.Parse(userID), "access", int.Parse(userID), nothing, 1, 0);

                                //Création de l'objet user 
                                object[] sessionUser = new object[4];
                                sessionUser[0] = resultArmsUser[0, 1]; //Login
                                sessionUser[1] = resultArmsUser[0, 3]; //ConnectionStrings
                                sessionUser[2] = userID; //UserID
                                sessionUser[3] = resultArmsUser[0, 4]; //connectionStringID
                                Session["sessionUser"] = sessionUser;

                                Session["userDb"] = null;
                                string res = string.Empty;
                                for (int a = 0; a < resultArmsUser.GetLength(0); a++)
                                {
                                    res += resultArmsUser[a, 5].ToString() + "#" + resultArmsUser[a, 4].ToString() + "{-}";
                                }
                                Session["userDb"] = res;


                                //Flag à true le champ actif de la table tblUser
                                user t = new user(resultArmsUser[0, 3], int.Parse(userID));
                                t.isActif = true;

                                if (Session["page"] != null)
                                {
                                    string page = Session["page"].ToString();
                                    if (page.Equals("finance.aspx"))
                                    {
                                        Response.Redirect("Finance/" + page);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Response.Redirect(page);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lbInfo.Text = myFunction.getResource("user_label_error_password_incorrect");
                                lbInfo.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                Session["logged"] = null;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lbInfo.Text = myFunction.getResource("user_label_error_password_incorrect");
                            lbInfo.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            Session["logged"] = null;
                        }

                        ContentPlaceHolder menuActive;
                        DropDownList cbbx_dbUser;
                        menuActive = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("menuActive");
                        cbbx_dbUser = (DropDownList)menuActive.FindControl("cmbx_dbListUser");
                        object[] myUserSession = (object[])Session["sessionUser"];

                        general_function myFunction_ = new general_function(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCI2ConnectionString"].ToString());
                        string resDbName = myFunction_.sql_request2D("getConnectionStringName " + myUserSession[3].ToString())[0, 0];

                        int index = 0;
                        for (int b = 0; b < cbbx_dbUser.Items.Count; b++)
                        {
                            string value = cbbx_dbUser.Items[b].Text;
                            //Si la corresspondance est parfaite avec la db utilisée actuellement on effetue la selection par defaut
                            if (value.ToLower().Trim().Equals(resDbName.ToLower().Trim()))
                            {
                                cbbx_dbUser.SelectedIndex = index;
                            }
                            index++;
                        }


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    general_function myFunction = new general_function(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCI2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                    lbInfo.Text = myFunction.getResource("user_label_enter_login");
                    lbInfo.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {

            }
```

Comment: please provide code behind code to handle this `btnClick` event

Comment: Okay sorry i have add this event code now

Comment: yes but what is strange is that everything works if I replace the "radTextBox" with "asp: textBox" ... Why? otherwise it does not matter I can replace